# Not able to call service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myServiceProvider <- myService
```

while calling a service in angularjs please help me to solve this issue

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'stringService', function ($scope, stringService) {
    $scope.output = stringService.processString(input);
}]);

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('stringService', function(){
    return{
        processString: function(input){
            if(!input){
                return input;
            }

            var output = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                if(i > 0 && input[i] == input[i].toUpperCase()){
                    output = output + " ";
                }
                output = output + input[i];
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: paste your code, or provide a working plnkr

Comment: var app = angular.module('app', []) , missing ";"

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope,   stringService)
```

you are injecting `myService` which doesn't exist. So, change to:

```
['$scope', 'stringService', function ($scope,   stringService)
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your factory as `stringService`, but you're trying to inject it as `myService`, if you do it as following it should work:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'stringService', function ($scope, stringService) {
    $scope.output = stringService.processString(input);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your second module line to this:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
```

If you pass 2 parameters, it defines a new module. If you pass one parameter, then it does a module lookup.

You should be defining the module once.

Answer (score 0):

your code defined two app named app, myService doesn't exist, it should change to stringService,
i think your code should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('stringService', function(){
return{
processString: function(input){
if(!input){
return input;
}
var output = "";
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
if(i > 0 && input[i] == input[i].toUpperCase()){
output = output + " ";
}
output = output + input[i];
}
return output;
}
}
});


app.controller('myController', 
['$scope', 'stringService', function ($scope, stringService) {
$scope.output = stringService.processString(input);
}]);
```